# Which of these series will be always convergent if $\sum a_n$ is convergent.?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let the series $\sum a_n$ be convergent. Then which of the following will always be convergent? $$\sum \left(a_n\right)^2\tag1$$ $$\sum \sqrt{a_n}\tag2$$ $$\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\tag3$$ $$\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^{1/4}}\tag4$$

I think we can immediately tell that the second option is not convergent since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ is a counter example. But I am not sure about the remaining three. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any other convergence tests?

Comment: I concluded that first, third and fourth are always true. Am I right? I am not sure. I have taken many counter examples and turned out that these options are true in each counter examples.

Comment: but have you actually proved it via tests?

Comment: Actually, I am not comfortable in proving these type of problems formally. I do these by taking counter examples. Can you please tell me how, the fourth one is divergent because  answer by Deep sea conclude that the fourth one is divergent. Thanks

Comment: Are you taking a calculus course with sequences & series? They should cover convergence tests for *these problems* IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

For d), try $a_{n}=\dfrac{1}{n(\log (n+1))^{2}}$, then $\dfrac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{n^{1/4}}=\dfrac{1}{n^{3/4}\log(n+1)}\geq\dfrac{1}{n\log(n+1)}$ and $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{n\log(n+1)}=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Series $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ can be a counter example for 1)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your series has positive terms: $a_n > 0$ for $n \ge 1$, then $a_n \to 0 \implies a_n < 1$ for $n \ge K \implies a_n^2 < a_n$. Thus $1)$ and $3)$ are always convergent. $3)$ is convergent by AM-GM inequality. $2)$ is divergent for $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: You can't assume  $a_n>0$, as the OP didn't mention such an assumption.

Comment: Thanks DeepSea, can you give me a counter example of the fourth option.

Comment: @Professor Vector if you do not assume that $a_n >0$ how is $\sqrt a_n$ in 2) defined?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Good question, but you'd have to ask the author of those problems, not me.

Comment: there can be series of complex numbers right?

Answer (score 0):

assuming positive $a_n$ terms:

First one converges since, after some terms, $(a_n)^2 $ is less than $a_n$

second one doesnt converge always, and your counter example works

third converges using A.M G.M inequality with $a_n$ and $\frac1{n^2}$

fourth doesnt converge always, $\frac1{n^{3/2}}$ will do for counterexample.